# Is Windows 10 Creators ISO bundled with Keeper Password Manager app?

Tags: windows-10, malware, bloatware

I downloaded Windows 10 Pro with Creators Update (version 1703) ISO from Microsoft's website. After performing a 64-bit clean installation, I discovered "Keeper Password Manager" in the list of installed apps. I never installed this app in previous Windows installations. Is this ISO supposed to come bundled with Keeper? I'm concerned on whether I downloaded a malware-containing illegitimate ISO, because this app has only 1,155 ratings in the [Store webpage](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/keeper-password-manager/9wzdncrdmpt6) (233 ratings in the Store app) and isn't developed by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is **yes**, and I noticed the same thing after my desktop was upgraded to version 1703 last Friday.  I had previously configured that machine to defer feature updates, but Microsoft made it available to every Windows 10 version 1607 computer (including the CBB and/or Semi-annual channel) last week.

There is plenty of [anecdotal evidence](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/6dpj78/keeper_password_manager_comes_preinstalled_now/) online:

> I just reinstalled Windows 10 today, and I was uninstalling all the bundled apps like usual, and I noticed that Keeper Password Manager is preinstalled now. I've never seen this come installed with Windows before.
>
> And this isn't a link to install it like some of the other apps, it's actually installed and opens.

The bottom line is that it is not malware, it's simply part of the standard Windows 10 Creators Update installation process.  I uninstalled it within my Windows profile and haven't see it since then.